# Symfony: How to get the current User Role in a Formtype or security.authorization_checker

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, symfony-2.3, symfony-3.1

I have a Formtype and I need to get access to the current Useres ROLE because I want to decide, which fields are beeing shown. 
Is it possible to get access to the `security.authorization_checker` for example so that I can make an if clause:

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_ADMIN')) { ....
```

Comment: you can make that FormType as a service then inject container and you can do like above.

Answer (score 5):

You can register your form as service and then pass `security.authorization_checker` as arguments, Check below sample code.

```
form.service.id:
    class: YourFormClass
    arguments: ['@security.authorization_checker']
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Then in your form class create `__construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)` method and then use `AuthorizationChecker` to check ROLE

Comment: No, in Symfony 3 it isn't allowed to have a constructor in a fromtype

Comment: No, I am using symfony 3.2 and it's allowed me to add __construct() in form, Where you find that symfony3* not allowed __construct in formType?

Event you can find __construct in symfony3.2 documentation, Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya fully agree with you we can use construct method in symfony form of any version.

Comment: What is the namespace of `AuthorizationChecker`?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can create your onw form based on this snipper of code I used in order to render a field at any NON-admin user:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue as TrueConstraint;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
    * @var AuthorizationChecker
    */
    private $authorizationChecker=null;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
    {
      $this->authorizationChecker=$authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.name","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'])
                ->add('surname',TextType::class,["label"=>"register.surname","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle']);

        if(!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        {
          $builder->add('accept_terms',CheckboxType::class,["label"=>"register.acceptTerms","required"=>true,'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                                                            'mapped' => false,'constraints' => new TrueConstraint(array('message' => 'Your Confirmation Message','groups' => 'Registration'))]);
        }
    }

   // Extra stuff ommited for convenience
}
```

So as you can see I use if a user is admin via `$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` piece of code.

SO you just have to put the `'@security.authorization_checker'` as service argument.